# How to use scipy minimize with a dataframe

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to select a subset of rows from a dataframe in order to fulfil certain constraints whilst maximising an objective. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100),
                   'b': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100),
                   'c': np.random.randint(0, 10, size=100),
                   'd': np.random.randint(0, 5, size=100)})

# constraint functions

def a_constraint(x0, df):
    return 1000 - df[x0].a.sum()

def c_constraint(x0, df):
    return 3 - df[x0].c.value_counts().max()

def d_constraint(x0, df):
    return 3 - df[(x0) & (df.d == 1)].shape[0]

def n_constraint(x0, df):
    return 15 - df[x0].shape[0]

# objective function
def objective(x0, df):
    return -df[x0].b.sum()

# initial guess
x0 = np.full((df.shape[0]), True, dtype=bool)

# optimization connstraints as list of dicts
constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': a_constraint, 'args': (df,)},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': d_constraint, 'args': (df,)},
               {'type': 'eq', 'fun': c_constraint, 'args': (df,)},
               {'type': 'eq', 'fun': n_constraint, 'args': (df,)},
               ]

result = minimize(objective, x0=x0, method='SLSQP', args=(df,), constraints=constraints)
```

However, I am getting a KeyError. It looks like it is treating my boolean array as column labels rather than an indexing mask. Has anyone got suggestions for where I am going wrong?

In response to hpaulj's comment below, the traceback is:

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Users\github\fpl\fpl_stackoverflow.py in <module>
     38                ]
     39 
---> 40 result = minimize(objective, x0=x0, method='SLSQP', args=(df,), constraints=constraints)

d:\Users\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    626     elif meth == 'slsqp':
    627         return _minimize_slsqp(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
--> 628                                constraints, callback=callback, **options)
    629     elif meth == 'trust-constr':
    630         return _minimize_trustregion_constr(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp,

d:\Users\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, bounds, constraints, maxiter, ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, finite_diff_rel_step, **unknown_options)
    327     # meq, mieq: number of equality and inequality constraints
    328     meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args']))
--> 329               for c in cons['eq']]))
    330     mieq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args']))
    331                for c in cons['ineq']]))

d:\Users\.conda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    327     # meq, mieq: number of equality and inequality constraints
    328     meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args']))
--> 329               for c in cons['eq']]))
...
-> 1308                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1309 
   1310             ax = self.obj._get_axis(axis)

KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,\n              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,\n              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,\n              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,\n              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,\n              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,\n              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,\n              1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],\n             dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"
```

The error is thrown before `print(x0)` in the objective function.

Comment: Add a debugging print to `objective` to see what `x0` gets passed to it.  Also when asking about errors show the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your formulation only works if you can guarantee that `x0` always has an integer or boolean `dtype`. Because `scipy.optimize.minimize` is for **contiguous** optimization problems, it uses a floating point `dtype` for the current iterate `x` under the hood, so that the first iteration already fails. That being said, your constraints are **not** continuously differentiable and thus, violate the mathematical assumptions of the underlying algorithms.

Long story short, you try to solve a discrete optimization problem with solvers for contiguous optimization problems. Formulating your problem as a discrete optimization problem is a much more convenient approach. A possible formulation and implementation in [python-mip](https://www.python-mip.com/) could look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mip import Model, BINARY, maximize

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100),
                   'b': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100),
                   'c': np.random.randint(0, 10, size=100),
                   'd': np.random.randint(0, 5, size=100)})

# extract the numpy arrays for easier access
a = df.a.values
b = df.b.values
c = df.c.values
d = df.d.values

N = 100

# Indices at which d[i] == 1
Td = np.argwhere(d == 1).flatten()

# For each unique value k in c we save each index i such that c[i] == k
Tc = {k : np.argwhere(c == k).flatten() for k in np.unique(c)}

# model object
mdl = Model()

# optimization / decision variables
# x[i] == 1 iff we select the i-th element in a,b,c,d and 0 otherwise
x = [mdl.add_var(var_type=BINARY) for i in range(N)]

# objective: maximize the sum of the selected elements in b
mdl.objective = maximize(sum(b[i]*x[i] for i in range(N)))

# constraint (a): the selected elements in a sum up to less-than 1000
mdl.add_constr(sum(a[i]*x[i] for i in range(N)) <= 1000)

# constraint (n): we select at most 15 elements
mdl.add_constr(sum(x[i] for i in range(N)) == 15)

# constraint (d): we select at most 3 elements for which d[i] == 1
mdl.add_constr(sum(x[i] for i in Td) <= 3)

# constraint (c): we select at most 3 elements of c with the same value
for value, Indices in Tc.items():
    mdl.add_constr(sum(x[i] for i in Indices) <= 3)

# disable the solver output
mdl.verbose = 0

# solve the optimization problem
mdl.optimize()

# extract the indices of the solution
selected = np.array([i for i in range(N) if x[i].x > 0.99])

print(selected)
```

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot of sense. Not accepted yet, only because I haven't had the chance to run the code yet. But will do later. Thanks for your response.